# Splitting field of polynomial over rational functions field

Tags: field-theory, rational-functions, splitting-field

I am looking to find the degree of the splitting field of $x^{p^n}-x-t$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}(t)$, the set of rational functions in $t$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$.

I would appreciate a hint rather than a full solution. Thank you.

Comment: It's an Artin-Schreier extension.

Comment: Hint: If $L/\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}(t)$ is a field extension and $\alpha \in L$ is a root of $f(x) := x^{p^{n}} - x - t \in (\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}(t))[x]$, then $\alpha + \xi$ is also a root of $f(x)$ for any $\xi \in \mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$.